# Real time address completion

Tags: ios, windows-phone-7, autocomplete

I'm working on an Windows Phone/iOS app (both native app), one feature I want is to have a **textbox** that auto-complete in a drop down menu as user enter a physical address (i.e. if user enter "new", the drop down should display "new york city, new orleans, etc", but only to city/county level).

Just like google's instant search complete: http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=106230

To be more specific,

1) where should I put this city name database? I suppose local is a good idea as for city level it won't be too big and there's no delay?
2) where can I get a complete north america city list?
3) and are there any open-source library that can do the autocomplete?

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify if this is a native app or web app. And please indicate what technologies you are trying to use. Such generic questions are difficult to answer.

Comment: It's native app. I don't know what technologies I want to use and that's exactly why I'm asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a WP7 point ov view. You can use the [AutoComplete box](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/autocompletebox-for-wp7-in-depth). Unless there is a good reason to have a dynamic list, I would backage the list of cities within the app as that will make the autocomplete quicker.

Comment: That's what I'm looking for, do you aware any similar implementation on iOS? Thanks!